# Plot a networkx graph in a bounding box

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx, bounding-box

I would like to generate a NetworkX graph in a 2D grid with boundaries (100, 100) i.e
x-axis ranges from (0,100) and y-axis ranges from (0,100).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx


H = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=8, m=9, seed=5)  # generate a random graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(H, iterations=500)  # find good positions for nodes
nx.draw(H)
print(pos)
plt.show()
```

I would like to know how to scale the coordinates of nodes stored in `pos`
such that all nodes lie within boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use the `scale` and `center` arguments of [`nx.spring_layout`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html)

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(H, iterations=500, scale=50, center=(50, 50))  # find good positions for nodes

# verify positions are withing boundaries 
positions_array = np.array(list(pos.values()))
print(((0 <= positions_array) & (positions_array <= 100)).all())
```

**Output**

```
True
```

The corresponding `pos` result (for one run) was:

```
{0: array([69.42667319, 77.61143687]), 1: array([81.63688581, 10.64742778]), 2: array([56.9561371,  0.       ]), 3: array([71.3536673 , 41.34120577]), 4: array([16.61575096, 54.76920418]), 5: array([17.06331411, 87.49081365]), 6: array([41.68768891, 28.49815199]), 7: array([45.25988262, 99.64175977])}
```